# Windows 10 and Linux dualboot disk encryption accessibility

Tags: windows, linux, disk-encryption, windows-10

I am considering buying Dell Latitude laptop which comes with Windows 10 preinstalled. I also want to install Kubuntu on it, so, in the end I will end up with a GRUB2 dualboot of Windows and Linux.

My question considering security. Will the Windows 10 programs or Windows 10 itself be able to read/write in/from my encrypted Linux partition?

I don't need to access the Linux partition from Windows. I just want to know if Windows side (installed programs or the Windows itself) will be able to access my encrypted Linux partition or not.

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific? You mean I need to encrypt the part of the disk where is GRUB2 bootloader too?

Comment: I don't understand. I will never use them together. Maybe I will have a 3rd partition to share files, but, this is not my problem. My problem is that I don't want Windows 10 or programs installed on it to access my Linux installation and files there. That's my only concern. Or are you saying that I have to use the same encrytion for the physical disk and cannot use Linux provided encryption for the linux partition and Winodows provided encryption for the Windows partition?

Comment: I will have at least 2 partitions on 1 physical hard disk. Probably more, I will see. I am talking about a dualboot. E.g. on my desktop I have Windows 7, Kubuntu, Debian and Manjaro and each of them is installed on a separate partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Linux partition is encrypted, it won't be readable at all unless it is decrypted with the correct key.

If the entire disk is encrypted by a single key and must be decrypted to boot into Windows, it could be possible to access the Linux filesystem, since it's on the same encrypted disk. I am not sure if this scenario is even applicable, so your answer is probably above.